# How to hide or delete HTML of Json and fetch() in Java script?

Tags: javascript, json

Problem: when adding 'energyEl', I want to hide or delete 'ul class="star-list"' in HTML However, if 'energy' is not True, want to display Ul.

I tried several methods, but the only way was to delete all uls or show them all.

Add the json data I created. I want to delete all reviews when the energy below is true. However, if star and view of json are left blank, text type 'review' remains. I want to make this part completely blank.

Here's a picture of the site

[image]

```
    "items":[
    {
       "sort":[1,3],
       "thumb":"./assets/img/deta-img1.webp",
       "loc":"all",
       "title":"abc",
       "review":{
           "star":"",
           "view":""
      },
       "price":{
            "ori":"",
            "sale":"",
            "curr":"80,000"
       },

      "energy":true,
```

I tried to do this:

```js
function list(sortNum, frame) {
  fetch('./assets/data/data.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      data = json.items;
      sortData = data.filter(function(parm) {
        return parm.sort.indexOf(sortNum) >= 0;
      })
      let html = ``;
      sortData.forEach(element => {
        onlyEl = `<span class="last-box a">ONLY</span>`;
        superhostEl = `<span class="last-box b">super</span>`;
        energyEl = `<div class="energy">
                        <span>
                            <img src="./assets/img/energy.svg" alt="">
                            energyx2
                        </span>
                    </div>`;

        if (element.only) {
          only = onlyEl;
        } else {
          only = '';
        }
        if (element.superhost) {
          superhost = superhostEl;
        } else {
          superhost = '';
        }

        if (element.energy) {
          energy = energyEl;
          $('.star-list').hide();
        } else {
          energy = '';
          $('.star-list').show();
        }
        html += `<li class="prd-item">
                <a href="" class="prd-link"></a>
                <div class="img-box">
                    <img src="${element.thumb}" alt="">
                    <button class="btn-fav" aria-label="like"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="text-box">
                    <em>${element.loc}</em>
                    <strong>${element.title}</strong>
                    <ul class="star-list">
                        <li class="star-item"><img src="${element.review.star}" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="star-item"><img src="${element.review.star}" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="star-item"><img src="${element.review.star}" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="star-item"><img src="${element.review.star}" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="star-item"><img src="${element.review.star}" alt=""></li>
                        <div class="review">review ${element.review.view}</div>
                    </ul>
                    ${energy}
                    <i class="bar"></i>
                    <div class="cost">
                        <em>${element.price.ori}</em>
                        <div class="sale">
                          <p class="per">${element.price.sale}</p>
                          <p>${element.price.curr}krw</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="last-box">
                    ${only}${superhost}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>`

      });
     $(frame).html(html);
    })
}
```

Comment: If I can make a suggestion... your code is wide open to various injection attacks right now.  When you interpolate text into the context of HTML, it must be escaped properly.  The easiest way I've found to do this is `lit-html`.  Even if you don't use Lit wholesale, its module for this makes things very simple, and solves the problem in your question as well.

Comment: Your `.forEach()` is _redefining_ the innerHTML of your `frame` element by doing `$(frame).html(html);` each time. Maybe you should be using `.append(html)` instead? Another point: your `$('.star-list').show()` or `$('.star-list').hide()` will affect _all_ `.star-list` items, not only the ones created in the current step of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet is still pretty messy, but maybe it can give you some ideas of how to do it in a slightly simplified way (I chose to work *without* jQuery here):

```js
const json = {
  "items": [
     {"sort": [1, 3],"thumb": "https://picsum.photos/id/237/60/40",
      "loc": "all","title": "abc","review": {"star": "","view": ""},"superhost": true,
      "price": {"ori": "","sale": "","curr": "80,000"},"energy": true},
    { "sort": [2, 3, 4],"thumb": "https://picsum.photos/id/238/60/40",
      "loc": "emea","title": "def","review": {"star": "","view": ""},
      "price": {"ori": "","sale": "","curr": "180,000"},"energy": false},
    { "sort": [1, 2, 3, 5],"thumb": "https://picsum.photos/id/239/60/40",
      "loc": "apa","title": "ghi","review": {"star": "","view": ""},"only": true,
      "price": {"ori": "90,000","sale": "40,000","curr": "50,000"},"energy": true}
  ]
};

function list(sortNum, frame) {
  /* fetch('./assets/data/data.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => { */
  data = json.items;
  sortData = data.filter(function(parm) {
    return parm.sort.indexOf(sortNum) >= 0;
  })
  frame.innerHTML = sortData.map(element => `<li class="prd-item">
                <a href="" class="prd-link"></a>
                <div class="img-box">
                    <img src="${element.thumb}" alt="">
                    <button class="btn-fav" aria-label="like">like</button>
                </div>
                <div class="text-box">
                    <em>${element.loc}</em>
                    <strong>${element.title}</strong>
                    <ul class="star-list ${element.energy?"hidden":""}">
                        <li class="star-item"><img src="${element.review.star}" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="star-item"><img src="${element.review.star}" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="star-item"><img src="${element.review.star}" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="star-item"><img src="${element.review.star}" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="star-item"><img src="${element.review.star}" alt=""></li>
                        <div class="review">review ${element.review.view}</div>
                    </ul>
                    ${element.energy?`<div class="energy"><span><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/20" alt="">energyx2</span></div>`:""}
                    <i class="bar"></i>
                    <div class="cost">
                        <em>${element.price.ori}</em>
                        <div class="sale">
                          <p class="per">${element.price.sale}</p>
                          <p>${element.price.curr}krw</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="last-box">
                    ${element.only?`<span class="last-box a">ONLY</span>`:""}${element.superhost?`<span class="last-box b">super</span>`:""}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>`).join("");
  // }) // end of .then(...)
}

list(3,document.getElementById("frame"));
```

```css
.hidden {display:none}
```

```html
<div id="frame"></div>
```